# Ajax request not changing HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I created a form with two selects and my idea was when the first select is changed, a query is made to the database and the second select is updated with new information.
Since is the first time I'm doing this kind of things, I tried insert some data from that query in a H3 tag instead of using a select tag, but something is not working... The H3 tag starts empty and after changing the select box, the H3 tag remains empty.

This is my code:

```
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#show-form-button").click(function(){
                $("#show-form-button").hide();
                $("#bot-form").show();
            });

            $("#distrito").on('change', function() {
                var selected = $(this).val();
                makeAjaxRequest(selected);
            });
        });

        function insertResults(json){
            alert("cenas");
            $("#teste").val(json["nome"]);
        }

        function makeAjaxRequest(placeID){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {placeId: placeID},
                dataType: "json",
                url: "http://localhost/Paulo%20Cristo%20LDA/insert.php",
                success: function(json) {
                    insertResults(json);
                }
            });
        }


    </script>
```

And this is my PHP script:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "paulocristo";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$placeId = $_GET["placeId"];

$query = "SELECT nome from local WHERE id =".$placeId ." AND tipo=0";

$result = $conn -> query($query) or die("Query failed");

if($result -> num_rows > 0)
{
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $row['nome'];
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
}

?>
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

I think the problem must be with AJAX because when I run [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fa0I3.png), the right information is being displayed in the browser.

Thanks for your patience and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: call the page in chrome and let us know what is in the console output when you change value?  you could also use the network tab in chrome dev tools to monitor the ajax call and inspect what it is returning.

Comment: Remove `echo $row['nome'];` if you echo ANYTHING along with the JSON response, the full response will not be valid JSON and the `success` function will not be called

Comment: Also, add and error function after your success function like the following to better see what is going wrong `, error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(xhr); }`

Comment: Oh, wait, also, dont echo your JSON for each row like that, that's not valid either.

Comment: @DelightedD0D
If I try to add that line of code: 
error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(xhr); } 
this error appears: (index):150 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

Comment: @flauntster there's no console output when I changed value

Comment: @AlexandreCristo please see my edit below for how to properly add the `error` function

Comment: Spaces in file paths is just a *bad practice*. Remove the spaces in the directory containing your PHP file and adjust the ajax call accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Remove echo `$row['nome'];` if you echo ANYTHING along with the JSON response, the full response will not be valid JSON and the success function will not be called

**2)** dont echo your JSON for each row like that, that's not valid either. –

Instead do this:

```
$response = [];
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $response[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

**3)** you're checking $_GET['placeId'] but your ajax is using type: "POST". Change your php to $placeId = $_POST["placeId"];

Additionally, and an error function after your success function in your AJAX like the following to better see what is going wrong:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {placeId: placeID},
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://localhost/Paulo%20Cristo%20LDA/insert.php",
            success: function(json) {
                insertResults(json);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                console.log(xhr); 
            }
        });
```

**4)** Remember also that the response will be *an array of rows not a single row* so you'll need to update your function like so:

```
 function insertResults(json){
        alert("cenas");
        $("#teste").val(json[0]["nome"]); // grab the 'nome' property from the first row in the response
 }
```

Comment: <h3 id="teste"> is still being display without anything inside :(

Comment: @AlexandreCristo you'll need to change also to `json[0]["nome"]` see my update

Comment: This line of code:
<code>error: function(xhr, status, error) { console.log(xhr); }</code> is breaking the rest of the code.
This message is being displayed after adding that code: (index):150 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: You likely forgot the comma between the functions. Please see my update for the full code

Comment: This error was displayed in the console:
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "Query failed", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: Then that means that your query is failing on this line: `$result = $conn -> query($query) or die("Query failed");` change that to `or die(mysqli_error($conn ));` to see why.

Comment: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma…e right syntax to use near 'AND tipo=0' at line 1", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Don't get it, my query works in the MySQL from the database

Comment: @AlexandreCristo what is the value of `$placeId` are you sure it is as expected? try `var_dump($_GET["placeId"]);` what does that return?

Comment: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "NULL↵You have an error in your SQL syntax; check t…e right syntax to use near 'AND tipo=0' at line 1", status: 200, statusText: "OK"} What??? how can that return NULL? When I write in the onchange function: alert(selected), it shows the right value!!

Comment: @AlexandreCristo Ah, you're checking `$_GET['placeId']` but your ajax is using `type: "POST"`. Change your php to `$placeId = $_POST["placeId"];`

Comment: sorry to just answer now. It's getting this error:
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "string(1) "1"↵You have an error in your SQL syntax…e right syntax to use near 'AND tipo=0' at line 1", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: What do you get if you call `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: I get this: Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "string(1) "1"↵You have an error in your SQL syntax…e right syntax to use near 'AND tipo=0' at line 1", status: 200, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: Is it possible to chat in another place? I can't use stackoverflow chat.

Comment: Sure, you can reach me on Skype at *dodsupport*.  `var_dump($_POST);` definitely should not return `"string(1) "1"` that should be an array. Are you sure you called `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: $placeId = var_dump($_POST["placeId"]); is this right?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP do this:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
  $arr[] = $row;
 }

echo json_encode($arr);
mysql_close($con);
```

**Also don't forget to do mysql_close($con) at the end. Hope this helps you!**

Comment: <h3 id="teste"> is still being display without anything inside :(

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are using `val()` on `h3` change your function to the following and use `html()`, The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input

```
function insertResults(json){
   alert("cenas");
   $("#teste").html(json["nome"]);
 }
```